# Connecting Laravel framework with Navicat

Tags: mysql, laravel, navicat

I am new to the Laravel framework; I have a task that should be completed using the Laravel framework and Navicat. The Navicat contains a database of the company. I have tried to use Xampp for the database, and it works, but when I try to connect it with Navicat, it shows nothing. Is there any way to make it connected with Laravel?

I have tried several times by changing the .env file following the database details. The error message shows that

> Access denied for the user 'root@172.16.0.97'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a permission issue to me. This error usually happens when the credentials in the .env file are incorrect or don't have sufficient permission to access the database.

You may follow these steps to try and resolve the problem:

1. Verify your database credentials: First of all, make sure that the database username and password that you're providing are correct. In your case, it seems like you're using the root user to connect to the database. Check if the password you have provided for this user is correct. If you're unsure of the password, try resetting it.
2. Ensure the root user has enough permission to connect to the database. If it doesn't, you may need to grant it the necessary privileges.
3. Check your connection details in your .env file, make sure that the host (DB_HOST) is set to the IP address of your database server (172.16.0.97). Also, make sure that the database name (DB_DATABASE), username (DB_USERNAME), and password (DB_PASSWORD) are all correctly set. Your .env settings should look something like this:
4. Check firewall settings if you're still facing issues, it might be related to your firewall settings. Make sure that your database server's firewall allows connections from your Laravel application.
5. Verify that you can connect to your database using Navicat with the same credentials and host information that you have in the Laravel .env file.
6. Use a different user if the root user is not working. You can try to create a new user in your MySQL database and grant it all the necessary privileges. Then, use this new user's credentials in your .env file.

If after trying all of these steps, you're still facing issues, you'll need your subject matter expert on your department to check on this.

Comment: I forgot to add some changes that I have made and run php artisan migrate it shows this error output "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"